# Access to the return value from the database by linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I need to send a value to database
this my code

```
var concerthallID = from _concert in db.tbl_Content_Context
    join _concerthall in db.tbl_Concert_ConcertHall on _concert.ContextID equals _concerthall.ContextID
    where _concert.EnContextID == concertid
    select _concerthall.ConcertHallID;
```

how to set ConcertHallID to a Variable?

Comment: Please give further information

Comment: I think i misunderstood the question do you mean you want to update the database or do you want to select the ID?

Comment: I want select a id and set the id value to a Variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query will return an Iqueryable, so if it will return one row or you need the first one use this after your code:

```
var ID = concerthallID.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to select a single `concert` and select the `id` from it after making sure it is not null, the code should be something like this:

```
var concert = (from _concert in db.tbl_Content_Context
    join _concerthall in db.tbl_Concert_ConcertHall on _concert.ContextID equals _concerthall.ContextID
    where _concert.EnContextID == concertid
    select _concert).SingleOrDefault();

var concerthallID = 0;
if (concert !=null)
    concerthallID = concert.ConcertHallID;
```

Remember to surround this with a `try catch` block to make sure that the single is returning only one.